# How do I make it so when I sign-up that account is able to log in to the database

Tags: php, mysql

So I am a newbie, to php/mysql and I would likeyou to see some code before I ask

Here is my two tables in by database

websiteusers(for  my sign-up page)

```
CREATE TABLE WebsiteUsers
(
userID int(9) NOT NULL auto_increment,
fullname VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
userName VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
email VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
pass VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(userID)
);
```

and username (mysql for login page)

```
CREATE TABLE UserName
(
UserNameID int(9) NOT NULL auto_increment,
userName VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
pass VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(UserNameID)
);
```

here is my two php scripts

connectivity.php (for login page)

```
<?php
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
define('DB_NAME', 'hhh');
define('DB_USER','root');
define('DB_PASSWORD','');

$con=mysql_connect(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD) or die("Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysql_error());
$db=mysql_select_db(DB_NAME,$con) or die("Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysql_error());
/*
$ID = $_POST['user'];
$Password = $_POST['pass'];
*/
function SignIn()
{
session_start();   //starting the session for user profile page
if(!empty($_POST['user']))   //checking the 'user' name which is from Sign-In.html, is it empty or have some text
{
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT *  FROM UserName where userName = '$_POST[user]' AND pass = '$_POST[pass]'") or die(mysql_error());
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($query) or die(mysql_error());
    if(!empty($row['userName']) AND !empty($row['pass']))
    {
        $_SESSION['userName'] = $row['pass'];
        echo "SUCCESSFULLY LOGIN TO USER PROFILE PAGE...";

    }
    else
    {
        echo "SORRY... YOU ENTERD WRONG ID AND PASSWORD... PLEASE RETRY...";
    }
}
}
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    SignIn();
}

?>
```

and connectivity-sign-up.php (for sign-up page)

```
<?php

define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
define('DB_NAME', 'hhh');
define('DB_USER','root');
define('DB_PASSWORD','');

$con=mysql_connect(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD) or die("Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysql_error());
$db=mysql_select_db(DB_NAME,$con) or die("Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysql_error());


function NewUser()
{
    $fullname = $_POST['name'];
    $userName = $_POST['user'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $password =  $_POST['pass'];
    $query = "INSERT INTO websiteusers (fullname,userName,email,pass) VALUES ('$fullname','$userName','$email','$password')";
    $data = mysql_query ($query)or die(mysql_error());
    if($data)
    {
    echo "YOUR REGISTRATION IS COMPLETED...";
    }
}

function SignUp()
{
if(!empty($_POST['user']))   //checking the 'user' name which is from Sign-Up.html, is it empty or have some text
{
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM websiteusers WHERE userName = '$_POST[user]' AND pass = '$_POST[pass]'") or die(mysql_error());

    if(!$row = mysql_fetch_array($query) or die(mysql_error()))
    {
        newuser();
    }
    else
    {
        echo "SORRY...YOU ARE ALREADY REGISTERED USER...";
    }
}
}
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    SignUp();
}
?>
```

So my question is is how could I make it so when a user signs-up, he/she is automatically inserted into my username database?

EDIT
no I have it connected to one table, and have changed it to mysqli but keep getting this error..

Notice: Undefined variable: con in C:\xampp\htdocs\test2\Sign-in\connectivity.php on line 12

Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\test2\Sign-in\connectivity.php on line 12

Notice: Undefined variable: con in C:\xampp\htdocs\test2\Sign-in\connectivity.php on line 12

Warning: mysqli_error() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\test2\Sign-in\connectivity.php on line 12

Comment: Why do you need a separate username table and websiteusers table? there's no information in username that isn't in websiteusers, so it's a little redundant.

Comment: so should i delete one of my tables

Comment: delete the one you currently use for the log-in page and use the websiteusers for both sign-up and log-in

Comment: Where do I edit my php to connect my sign-in page to websiteusers

Comment: @nathan32100 - all you need to do is replace every occurrence of `username` with `websiteusers`. Since the fields are the same, that should be enough.

Comment: Two suggestions, firstly drop the mysql_* its been depreciated use mysqli_ or pdo instead and secondly please please please at the VERY least md5 their passwords.

Comment: thanks ill see if it works..> Clark T. "md5"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***EDITED SO THAT IT USES mysqli***_:

```
<?php
 $DB_HOST= "localhost";
 $DB_NAME = "hhh";
 $DB_USER = "root";
 $DB_PASSWORD= "";

     $con= mysqli_connect($DB_HOST,$DB_USER,$DB_PASSWORD,$DB_NAME) or die("Failed to connect to MySQL");                  
       function SignIn($con)
        {
        session_start();   
          if(!empty($_POST['user'])){
          $query = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT *  FROM websiteusers WHERE userName = '$_POST[user]' AND pass = '$_POST[pass]'") or die(mysqli_error($con)); //changed
          $row = mysqli_fetch_array($query) or die(mysqli_error($con));
          if(!empty($row['userName']) && !empty($row['pass'])) //changed to a more modern operator
            {
             $_SESSION['userName'] = $row['pass'];
             echo "SUCCESSFULLY LOGIN TO USER PROFILE PAGE...";

             }
          else
            {
               echo "SORRY... YOU ENTERD WRONG ID AND PASSWORD... PLEASE RETRY...";
             }
          }
       }
      if(isset($_POST['submit']))
      {
        SignIn($con);
        }

    ?>
```

Comment: it means that php believes it is insecure and will remove that syntax from the future versions of php

Comment: I tried your code and it saying  "syntax error, unexpected 'function' (T_FUNCTION) in C:\xampp\htdocs\test2\Sign-in\connectivity.php on line 9"

Comment: sry...forgot a "; " .. fixed it :)

Comment: one more question, when I type in a wrong username and password,it does not say "SORRY... YOU ENTERD WRONG ID AND PASSWORD... PLEASE RETRY..." it just goes blank, how could I make it so it can say that

Comment: md5 is an encryption type...i advise you not to use it because it is broken.... try using the blowfish encryption instead...more about encryptions here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php

Comment: to check for username/pass combination you must compare the input with the existent values at the given username (if any)

Comment: @SpiderLinked You shouldn't encrypt passwords but instead use a 1 way hash. But it has should be a slow one like scrypt, bcrypt or PBKDF2.

Comment: Notice: Undefined variable: con in C:\xampp\htdocs\test2\Sign-in\connectivity.php on line 12

Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\test2\Sign-in\connectivity.php on line 12

Notice: Undefined variable: con in C:\xampp\htdocs\test2\Sign-in\connectivity.php on line 12

Warning: mysqli_error() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\test2\Sign-in\connectivity.php on line 12 (this happened when it was changed to mysqli???????)

Comment: ... i said "encrypt"....sry for the missunderstanding... you are right @Casey...next time i will use the term "one way hash"...:|

Comment: yea..nathan..is because it does not reconise $con as a conection..fixing that now..

Comment: still having the same problems

Comment: could it be that my php is out of date?

Answer (score 0):

You just need 1 table. When they sign up insert them into the database and then call the log in function and in the log in process use $_SESSION cookie to mark them as logged in. Also for the love of god you a begging for an injection attack. mysql_query is deprecated use PDO or MySQLi and use parameters.

Comment: just mysqli or "mysqli_query